# Jquery how to get a hiddenfield with a particular data attribute and set another data attribute

Tags: jquery

I have the hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" class="deleted" name="Deleted" data-id="2" value="@Model.Deleted" />
```

so there is going to be a few of these on the page but with different data-id values.

I'm wanting to get this particular one and set the value to true.

To get all hidden fields would be?

```
$(':hidden')
```

However I only want to get ones with `class="deleted"` so this would be?

```
$(':hidden.deleted')
```

Now I want to narrow it down to the one with `data-id="2"`

How to do this?

Comment: `$(':hidden.deleted[data-id=2]')`

Comment: `$('.deleted:hidden').filter('[data-id=2]')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('.deleted[data-id="2"]:hidden')
```